# Why are the results different in these two select values in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

Why are the results different A and B in MariaDB?

```
SELECT 23033848 * 0.1248 * 11407967/ 23423423 AS 'A', 
23033848 * 0.1248 * (11407967/ 23423423) AS 'B'


"A":"1400035.27058379"  

"B":"1400035.27026258"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Floating point arithmetic, by definition, is not exact. While the `A` and `B` results are mathematically identical, the two floating point results from your query are not...at least not quite exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the answer were just "`FLOAT` is broken", then I would expect `A` and `B` to agree to about 16 significant digits, since that is the precision available in `DOUBLE`.

However, the results agree to only about 10 digits, so something else is going on.

This is what you have (adding parens to clarify):

```
SELECT (23033848 * 0.1248 *  11407967) / 23423423  AS 'A', 
        23033848 * 0.1248 * (11407967  / 23423423) AS 'B'
```

Adding some trailing zeros on gives:

```
mysql> SELECT 23033848.00 * 0.124800000000000000 * 11407967.00/ 23423423.00 AS 'A',
              23033848.00 * 0.1248000000000000 * (11407967.00/ 23423423.00) AS 'B' ;
+------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| A                                  | B                                |
+------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1400035.27058379113932237828775068 | 1400035.270583791139265109708800 |
+------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Shows that *probably* `A` is closer to "correct".

So, what is `B` doing "wrong"?

```
mysql> SELECT 11407967/ 23423423, 11407967./ 23423423., 11407967.00/ 23423423.00;
+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
| 11407967/ 23423423 | 11407967./ 23423423. | 11407967.00/ 23423423.00 |
+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
|             0.4870 |               0.4870 |                 0.487032 |
+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%div%';
+---------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name             | Value |
+---------------------------+-------+
| div_precision_increment   | 4     |
```

So, I'll bet something is going on with switching to `DECIMAL` and playing with the number of decimal places.

(The rest of this Answer is left as an exercise.

OK, I don't know the rest of the Answer.)